# Redirect ip to url using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect from my ip(A host) to my website url. Earlier I used the following lines in the .htaccess file and it worked fine.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){3} [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The above code redirected my ip to the web url.

Now I changed the code to the following and the ip redirects to a weird url

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){3} [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I want to use the {REQUEST_URI} feature and at the same time redirect to my base url. What is the correct syntax to do that ?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){3} [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: It shows moved permanently message but its not redirecting if I use the above code...